# Yocto core-image-rt compilation error

Tags: linux, arch-linux, real-time, beaglebone, yocto-project

I am trying to build the 'core-image-rt' on BeagleBone platform. 
But I am getting following error:

```
ERROR: Nothing PROVIDES 'core-image-rt'
ERROR: core-image-rt was skipped: Set PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/kernel to linux-yocto-rt to enable it
```

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

In conf/local.conf:

PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/kernel = "linux-yocto-rt"

You can find the related script in
/meta/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-yocto-rt_4.x.bb

Comment: It is preferable to include more details in your answer